# как сделать что бы у Имя,Фамилия можно было вводить только буквы,а у Номер телефона только цифры?

Tags: python

```
def input_characters(self):
        self.last_name = input("Введите фамилию: ")
        self.name = input("Введите имя: ")
        self.phone_number = input("Введите номер телефона: ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re


while True:
    last_name = input('Введите фамилию: ')
    if not re.findall(r'\d', last_name):
        print("Отлично")
        break
    else: print("Данные введены неверно, попробуйте еще раз")


while True:
    name = input('Введите имя: ')
    if not re.findall(r'\d', name):
        print("Отлично")
        break
    else: print("Данные введены неверно, попробуйте еще раз")

while True:
    number = input('Введите номер телефона: ')
    if not re.findall(r'\D', number):
        print("Отлично")
        break
    else: print("Данные введены неверно, попробуйте еще раз")
```

Comment: Можно обойтись и стандартными методами строки(`str.isalpha()` и `str.isdigit()`), a не тянуть модуль re.